# Tool which shows me which files are written in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, iostat

I found in IOStat, that some part of my application is writing extensively, but I don't know which process it is and what files it is writing to. In Vista there is a tool fo that which shows the files that have been active in the last 30 Seconds. Is there something similar for Linux?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: I know filemon, but what tool in Vista are you referring to?

Comment: @Ludwig  Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Reliability and Performance Monitor. Then click the bar which says Disk. It shows the most active files and which processes are reading or writing.

Comment: It's on ServerFault already: http://serverfault.com/questions/224629/see-what-files-are-being-written-to-like-iotop-but-for-files-not-processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`lsof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof).
It's a command line tool but there is also a [GUI for it at sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/glsof).

Comment: lsof is only going to show you the files the process has open <em>now</em>

Answer (score 9):

```
strace -e trace=file -- <command>
```

will show you exactly what files your application is reading and writong

Comment: Will strace work on an entire process tree, or just one process?

Comment: It won't work on a whole tree but you can use the '-p pid' option to attach to up to 32 processes

Comment: or use '-f' to trace child processes as they are created by currently traced processes as a result of the fork(2) system call

Answer (score 8):

If you want to see all the file accesses in real time (up to 32 processes) you can use this command:

```
strace -f -e trace=file `ps aux | tail -n +2 | awk '{ORS=" "; print $2}' | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\)/\-p \1 /g' | sed -e 's/\-p  $//g'`
```

Comment: system crashed a few seconds after pasting this into ssh, afraid to try again :o 

where does the 32 processes limit come from?

Answer (score 3):

> To find all files modified in the last
>   24 hours (last full day) in a
>   particular specific directory and its
>   sub-directories:
>
> find /directory_path -mtime -1 -print

more at:

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/01/19/find-files-that-are-modified-today-or-since-certain-time-ago-in-unix/

Comment: And is there also some way to monitor the activity (read write kb/s) on individual files? The server is quite active and many files get changed, but I need those with the highest transfer...

Answer (score 3):

lsof will list all open files for a given process:

lsof -p

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of a program but the find command in utility has a lot of options which will allow you to find files and/or directories that have been modified within a certain time period.

For example:

```
$ find /home/you -iname "*.txt" -mtime -1 -print
```

Would find text files that were last modified 1 days ago.

You could wrap this call in some sort of script or write your own quick little app to use the results.

Here's a site with some more info and examples:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-files-by-date/

Answer (score 1):

Linux provides a file change notification API called "dnotify", along with a command line utility [dnotify](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dnotify). You can use that to keep track of the changes over the last 30s.

I would probably write an application that builds directly on the Linux API, and discards all events older than 30s.